# Problems when copy pasting a sheet in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive

I have recently started using spreadsheets in the cloud, and having some problems with the most basic of tasks.

I have a location in my google drive. There there is a spreadsheet. This has only one sheet. I wanted to add one sheet and do some diagram there, but instead of doing it right there, I donwloaded the google spreadsheet to my machine, and added a sheet with the diagram. Then I uploaded the file to google drive.

So now I have two similar spreadsheets MySpreadsheet.xlsx and MySpreadsheet(1).xlsx in the drive. I open both and now I want to copy paste the sheet with the diagram. Something pretty simple in Excel.

So I go to the MySpreadsheet(1).xlsx and I click the sheet and in the menu "copy to another sheet" and then "Existing spreadsheet"

I got a window with many documents(My Drive,Common Items, Common Drive , Items used recently) , but no matter what I search , there is no MySpreadsheet.xlsx anywhere.
There is even a place to put the web address and I put the URL of MySpreadsheet.xlsx and no, it does not find it, and gives an error.

So, how can I overcome this error and copy paste a sheet to another spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can copy a tab from an Excel spreadsheet to another using Google Sheets. You can, however, copy a tab from an Excel spreadsheet to a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

Open the 'MySpreadsheet.xlsx' file and choose **File > Save as Google Sheets**. Then copy the tab you have in 'MySpreadsheet(1).xlsx' to the new Google Sheets file.

Comment: Now I have three copies! it is so strange. Oh! I understood your first line. Thanks!